# Windows Forms custom control painting stops

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, paint

I"m making a custom control that draws my simulation. The problem is, that when constantly invalidating it (which is needed because each tick the appeareance is changed) it blocks other controls from being drawn (for example the property grid is not updating as long as I'm dragging an object in the simulation with my mouse).

How can i prevent this behaviour? How does the drawing of windows forms work? Also when having two instances of this control on the form the first one blocks the second one. So only one gets drawn and the other just stays blank.

Anyone here who already made complex user controls? I cant use other rendering mechanisms, because the program is supposed to be used in office environments which might not have a suitable graphics card for hardware accelerated drawing.

//edit:found the problem. I had an Invalidate() in my drawcall in a submethod *facepalm*

Comment: When you say drawing every tick, how often are you referring to?

Comment: when dragging a part of the simulation i want it to be updated live. so every mouse move event in this case.

Comment: Ideally, this is only every `MouseMove` event when you're actually dragging something, correct? The big thing to keep in mind is to always invalidate when you actually need it and ideally only the region that needs to be repainted.

Comment: well mouse move is pretty fast. i think i'd cap it(the simulation redraw) at 50 times per second. when only having one control on the form it also draws with 2000 objects in it. it just slows down. but i dont get why the hell my control blocks other controls from being drawn. also i cant determine which parts to redraw when doing the simulation as it is cheaper to just draw it. imagine 100 objects which all change a small part. the connection lines also change color. doesnt make sense to check for all this ( my point of view, correct if wrong)

Comment: I've drawn some (what I believe to be) complex custom controls before, but never experienced what you are describing. I just wanted to cover the core questions in-case you may have been just overloading the CPU with constant drawing. Drawing only the parts you need may be what you need to do, though you may need to represent your objects using a more sophisticated data structure to more easily determine what objects are effected.

Comment: it also blocks others even if it doesnt draw anything. when no objects are in it and i turn of the grid and coordinates it basically does nothing. but the second instance is still not drawn. what might be the problem is, that im calling invalidate while it didnt redraw the control yet. so like calling it twice or more. i already tinkered with that feature, and got it a bit to work, but when resizing the form it locks up again and stops redrawing itself.

Comment: @fredlllll If you solved your problem you can post an answer and mark it as accepted. Check out [this article on self-answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, dirty workaround incoming:

i used a forms timer to constantly redraw my stuff. that keeps the gui from locking up. its ugly...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but you may want to look at the Form.OnIdle event.

This event occurs when your app's message queue goes empty, which implies that all *other* UI updating and user-event handling is done (for the moment). Unless you've got something that's generating a constant stream of messages all the time, they tend to come in bursts during UI interaction. The end of a burst is a pretty good time to update your custom control.

The timer isn't a messy hack at all, IMO. It's a good way to establish a minimum update frequency. Typically, updates are only necessary when the information being displayed changes, or a window covers and then uncovers yours, forcing a redraw. But if you're not tracking changes that way, or the underlying information is changing hundreds of times per second, a timer is a good way to throttle your updates so that they only happen within a certain frequency range.